# How do I update common fields in multiple feature classes with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, editing, update, list

I have a piece of code that I can use to update several fields in a specific feature class.  I would like to use this code to update all of the feature classes in the data set.  The data set would would be WATER and the feature classes would be WATERLINES, HYDRANTS, VALVES, AIR_RELEASE, ETC)  Each of the feature classes have the fields I would like to update:  LASER_LINK, ASSETID.

Here is the code i use to update a single feature class called WATERLINES:

```
# Python Script: updateAttributes.py
# This script autopopulates the LASER_LINK and ASSETID fields.

print "Start script: " 

# Import the ArcPy package
import arcpy
import os

# feature class to be updated
fc = 'C:\Users\cbgibson\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\TEST_WSdata.sde\waterlines'

# set the current workspace
workspace = os.path.dirname(fc)

# start edit session
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace) # Start an edit session. Must provide the worksapce.  
edit.startEditing(False, True) # Edit session is started without an undo/redo stack for versioned data(for second argument, use False for unversioned data)
edit.startOperation()# Start an edit operation 

updateFieldsList =  ["Laser_Link", "Project_nu", "IDNAME", "IDNUMBER", "IDNUMBER2", "ASSETID"]  

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, updateFieldsList) as cursor:  
    for row in cursor:  
         row[0] = "http://lf/weblink8WaterandSewer/search.aspx?dbid=0&searchcommand={[]:[WS Project Number]=" + '"' + str(row[1]) + '"}'
         row[5] = row[2] + str(row[4])
         cursor.updateRow(row)

# exit edit session
edit.stopOperation() # Stop the edit operation.  
edit.stopEditing(True)# Stop the edit session and save the changes

print "Finished attribute update: "
```

I did figure out how to return all of the feature classes from the WATER data set by using this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:\Users\cbgibson\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\TEST_WSdata.sde"
fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "", "Water")

print fc
```

Im just not sure how to return all of the feature classes and run the update against every feature class.  Im sort of a newb at this and have been reading through quite a bit of material.  Enough to get me this far anyway.  Im just stuck!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your feature classes in a list, and looop through it and then perform the update cursor on the common fields.  Here is some mock code:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\Users\cbgibson\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\TEST_WSdata.sde'

fcList ['WATERLINES', 'HYDRANTS', 'VALVES', 'AIR_RELEAS']

for fcName in fcList:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcName, commonFieldsList) as cursor:
        # continue with logic
```

Comment: How does this fit into the code when the workspace is set as:

workspace = os.path.dirname(fc)

workspace is also called here:

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(workspace)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The method you described worked perfectly!!!!  Thanks a ton!